# change var value onscroll Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am making a function and i have added if statement at the top of it. I want to change variable value when user scroll. If the user scroll if statement check variable value and run the function inside if statement

```
var usrscrolled = 'notscroll';
    function scrolled() {
        //do by scroll start
        usrscrolled = 'scroll';
    }
    $(window).on('scroll', scrolled);
    if (usrscrolled = 'notscroll') {

}
```

this code works but onscroll variable dont change and if statement runs on scroll

Comment: Use comparison operator `==` not assignment operator `=` in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is used to assign value, to compare you need to use `==`, so change

```
if (usrscrolled = 'notscroll') {
```

to

```
if (usrscrolled == 'notscroll') {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing that the `if` statement is not running after there's been a scroll:

```
// Unnecessary if; usrscrolled will always be 'notscroll' here
// This does _not_ run on scroll
if (usrscrolled === 'notscroll') {

}
```

If you want that, you need to wrap it in the `on` handler, i.e. like this:

```
function scrolled() {
    if (usrscrolled === 'notscroll') {
        // Do something before the variable is set to 'scroll'
        // I.e. first time user scrolls
    }
    usrscrolled = 'scroll';
}
$(window).on('scroll', scrolled);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added this code

```
var delay = 1000;
var timeout = null;
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        usrscrolled = 'notscroll';
    }, delay);
});
```

It changes variable value after 1 second when user stops scrolling. And it works for me